# How to limit the number of relationships shown in "Graph" display?

Tags: neo4j

I have a simple database with two nodes and two relationships between them.
[image: example neo4j database with two nodes and two relationships]

My goal is to execute a Query that will display only the "LIKES" relationship.
The "LIKES" relationship has a property "testprop" and value "TestVal".
When I execute the following query:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->() WHERE r.testprop="TestVal" RETURN r;
```

The result in the "Graph" display of the browser is the same as the image above. Displaying all nodes and all relationships.
When I select the "Rows" tab, the result is:

```
r 
testprop    TestVal
```

Why does the "Graph" display in the browser render all Relationships and all Nodes as a result of this query, which returns only a single relationship?

Further more, when you export the result of this query to JSON:

{"**columns**":["r"],"data":[{"row":[{"testprop":"TestVal"}],"**graph**":{"nodes":[{"id":"4","labels":["Person"],"properties":{"name":"Alice","age":23}},{"id":"5","labels":["Person"],"properties":{"name":"Bruce","age":43}}],"relationships":[{"id":"4","type":"LIKES","startNode":"4","endNode":"5","properties":{"testprop":"TestVal"}}]}}],"stats":{"contains_updates":false,"nodes_created":0,"nodes_deleted":0,"properties_set":0,"relationships_created":0,"relationship_deleted":0,"labels_added":0,"labels_removed":0,"indexes_added":0,"indexes_removed":0,"constraints_added":0,"constraints_removed":0}}

You will notice that there's a separate object for the "**Rows**" display in the browser, containing the correct results from the query, and a "**Graph**" object containing I guess everything in the database?

Can someone explain why?
And how to display only the "LIKES" relationship in "Graph" view in the browser?

Thank you!

Comment: Does `MATCH ()-[r:LIKES]->() WHERE r.testProp="TestVal" RETURN r` give you the same thing?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same as before in Graph and Rows view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little option button in the bottom right corner of the visualisation that you can set to **off** to only show your part of the graph :

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This change had the intended effect on the Graph display.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the Cypher query specifies a **Node** or a **Relationship** as a `RETURN` item, the Browser will display a graphical visualization, as that is what the Browser is normally used for. On the other hand, if the query specified a **property** as a `RETURN` item, it would display the property in tabular form.

   Try the following query, which returns a property instead of a Relationship.

   ```
   MATCH ()-[r]->()
   WHERE r.testprop="TestVal"
   RETURN r.testprop;
   ```
2. The response contains a "graph" object because you are requesting a dump of the Browser's results.

   In your case, the Browser result was a graphical visualization of your results, so your download included the data for that graph.

   If you tried my query above and then downloaded its results, you would see that the "graph" object contains empty "nodes" and "relationships" arrays, since the Browser result was non-graphical.